# Neo4j Desktop 1.3.8 : "Failed - not a valid password" after using 'Reset database password'

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

From the desktop application I went to database>manage>administration.
[image]
There I filled in a new password (I tried several) and pressed 'apply'. After restarting the database I get the following prompt: `Local Graph password has been changed. Please enter Graph password:`. When I fill in the new password (I also tried the default, `neo4j`) I get this error... `Failed - not a valid password.`
[image]

I can still run the database with `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false`, but I just want to figure out how to get this fixed. I tried all sorts of solutions. If someone could help me set this up correctly that'd be very much appreciated.

edit note: Everything worked the previous days. After the last pc restart it suddenly didn't anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on the neo4j forum ([here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/failed-not-a-valid-right-after-resetting-password/26659)) and got a response from [wookiefrits](https://community.neo4j.com/u/wookiefritz) with the following instructions:

> 1. Disable authentication in your settings by setting:
>    `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false`
> 2. Then all you have to do is to go to your Neo4j Browser and paste this into the shell:
>    `ALTER USER neo4j SET PASSWORD 'mynewpassword';`
> 3. set `dbms.security.auth_enabled` back to `true`

Comment: I was able to do this method without errors, but once I turn `auth_enabled` back to true it doesn't accept my new password.

Comment: wehre is this config-file if you use the app image (`neo4j-desktop-canary-1.5.8-dev.0-x86_64.AppImage`) ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for this. I just used the change password via cypher-shell and everything synced back up again.